# Very simple question regarding looping in app script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I guess this is very stupid, because it is easy. I tried to find an answer on google, but could not find a solution.

I am doing some basic looping:

```
function Testing_Loops() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 3;i<=lr;i++){

      var Clients = ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();

        }
}
```

In column 2 I have some rows with clients' names. I want to store these in a variable. My problem is that, at this moment, the only client, I have in the "Clients" variable is the one which is in the last row. This makes sense, because my loop is overwriting my variable each time.

How do I store all the names in on variable? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDataRange()` for getting the current values

```
function Testing_Loops() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var clients = ss.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(row){
    return row[1];
  });

  Logger.log(clients);
}
```

If you need map it to html for an email try something like this

```
/**
 *
 */
function getHtmlListForEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var clients = ss
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    .map(function(row) {
      return Utilities.formatString('<li>%s</li>', row[1]);
    })
    .join('\n');

  return Utilities.formatString('<ul>%s</ul>', clients);
}

/**
 *
 */
function sendMail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail('contributor.pw', 'Title', '', {
    htmlBody: getHtmlListForEmail()
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list as such:

```
final List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, loop through and add them:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();

for (var i = 3;i<=lr;i++){
    clients.add(ss.getRange(i,2).getValue());
}
```

Then, you can print out what you have:

```
for (final Client client : clients) {
     System.out.println(client);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java in Apps Script? Is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to store multiple client names in one array. 
I did it this way:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var allEmail = ss.getRange(1, 13).getValue();
  var listClientsNames=[];  


  for (var i = 3;i<=lr;i++){

        var originallist = ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();
        listClientsNames.push(originallist);
        }


  //MailApp.sendEmail(allEmail, "Title", listClientsNames);


}
```

I am now trying to send client list to my email. It is working fine. However, I am receiving the list like this:
client1, client2, clent3 and so on.

Can I somehow (in an easy way) do something so it appears vertically:
Client 1
Client 2
Client 3

thank you so much for all the help!! I appreciate it alot!

Comment: var liststr=listClientsNames.join("<BR>");

Comment: I updated my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58358226/1393023